# Is MeteorJS still en vogue to learn?

Tags: meteor

I am about to learn my next programming language. I came across MeteorJS and am curious if it is still a good idea to learn more about it, is it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. An answer would most likely be opinion based, making it a bad fit for questions here. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in my opinion Meteor is somewhat underestimated. In combination with React you can create great web applications. 
I can only recommend learning it.